# Is it possible to get an image of environment in OpenAI gym?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

In environments like Atari space invaders state of the environment is its image, so in following line of code

`observation, action, reward, _ = env.step()` `observation` variable holds the actual image of the environment, but for environment like Cartpole the observation would be some scalar numbers.

Is it possible to somehow access the picture of states in those environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
env.render(mode="rgb_array")
```

This would return the image (array) of the rendering which you can store. The camera angles can be set using distance, azimuth and elevation attributes of env.viewer.cam

Answer (score 1):

Using 'img = env.render(mode='rgb_array')' return the rendered image.
See for example the following code:

```
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()

img = env.render(mode='rgb_array')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

env.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import gym
env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
env.reset()
env.env.ale.saveScreenPNG('test_image2.png')
```

Comment: Just to provide more info about this solution/answer. `ale` is a field of the environment and stands for "Arcade Learning Environment (ALE)" (see https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/atari/atari_env.py#L58). See https://github.com/openai/atari-py/blob/master/atari_py/ale_python_interface.py#L298. So, this solution should work for the Atari environments, where you can access `saveScreenPNG`. Also, the question was about non-Atari environment, but [Breakout](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Breakout-v0/) is an Atari environment.